# Com error 800a03ec when i call PrintPreview() method of workbook

Tags: c++, excel, com, ole

Show message of Com error 800a03ec when i can PrintPreview() of workbook

```
m_spWorkbook->PrintPreview();
```

i get m_spWorkbook in the following code:

```
hr = spOleObject->QueryInterface(__uuidof(_Workbook), (void**)&m_spWorkbook);
```

what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception 800a03ec often means problem with locale. For example, language in Excel differs from regional settings. Have a look at these links:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eric_carter/archive/2005/06/15/429515.aspx
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320369

---

As I understood from your other question, HRESULT 0x800a03ec throwing may be assotiated with instances of Excel. Perhaps, in moment, when you are calling `printPreview` application is already closed or you are trying create additional instance of Excel or user editing in your instance of Excel

Comment: No, application isn't closed. I try to call printPreview for OLE object of Excel Chart.

Comment: I can press Ctrl + P and Print Dialog is happen.

Comment: Are `Workbook.SaveAs` & `excel.Workbooks.Open` work fine in your app?

Comment: @G-71: I'm meaning if you can programmatically call `SaveAs` for your Workbook-object?

Comment: wait a minute please. I trying it.

Comment: Did you check out locale issue in first part of the answer?

Comment: No, there is no problems with locale, because i try to work with excel objects without OLE. I use Excel::_ApplicationPtr app("Excel.Application");. I hadn't a problem.

Comment: And We aren't set the locale setting in the PrintPreview  method

Comment: I mean: what is language 

1. in your regional settings

2. in your Visual Studio

3. in your Excel

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but this may have to do with Security Permissions. My hunch would be (I haven't tested this specifically), that `PrintPreview` internally uses macro functions or is trying to get access to VBA Project model; either of which may be denied if the macro security is set to default level (or higher!).

Try giving VBA Macros "Enable all macros" security level to see if this solves the problem. If it does then you will probably want to have a signed application whose certificate is trusted by VBA in production environment. Or you can lower VBA security on all involved computers but of course that isn't recommended at all.