# Runtime error in VBScript for Excel

Tags: vbscript

When I run a VBScript for excel sheet....

I get the unknown runtime error, code: **800A03EC**.

I am stuck at the line

```
Do Until objExcel.cells(line,3).Value = ""
```

What could be the possible reason for getting such an error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Com error 800a03ec when i call PrintPreview() method of workbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377069/com-error-800a03ec-when-i-call-printpreview-method-of-workbook)

Comment: Perhaps you missed the Worksheet object in your code? `objExcel.Worksheets("YourWorkSheetNameHere").Cells(line,3).Value`

Comment: @PatricK The application object provides a `Cells` collection too (refers to the cells of the active sheet).

Comment: Thanks @AnsgarWiechers, didn't notice it's available, but I feel it's not a good practice to use it. @Shilpita, can you add some `wscript.echo` lines to indicate where the error is? Assuming you are using cscript.